# How to make grid to load faster even though the table contains more than 100K records?

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, performance, grid

I'm facing a issue with a Magento site, Its on 1.7 version and We are having good server configurations.

We are using AheadWorks FollowUp extension, The email log table contains 100K records, The admin grid is taking 10minutes of time to load.

How to make the grid to load faster? Is there any way out.

We don't want to delete the records.

Everything is fine except that.

The table structure is :

```
mysql> desc aw_followup_queue;
```

`+-----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| code            | varchar(128)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at      | datetime              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| scheduled_at    | datetime              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sent_at         | datetime              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sequence_number | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| sender_email    | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sender_name     | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| recipient_name  | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| recipient_email | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject         | varchar(255)          | YES  |     |         |                |
| content         | mediumtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status          | enum('R','S','F','C') | NO   |     | R       |                |
| rule_id         | int(11) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| object_id       | int(11)               | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| params          | text                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

Is there any mysql optimization will help to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the problem comes with MySQL ? If so, you can add indexes on the most frequent filters you use in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not 100% sure about this but I think the problem is the `select all` and `unselect all` buttons in the grid.
When you click 'select all', not only the items shown in the grid are selected. All of the items in the db are selected. In order to be able to select all items magento adds a json object at the end of the grid containing all the ids of all the records in the db.

See this in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/massaction.phtml`.

```
<?php if(!$this->getParentBlock()->canDisplayContainer()): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.setGridIds('<?php echo $this->getGridIdsJson() ?>');
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the method `getGridIdsJson` is the culprit in this case. See how `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction_Abstract::getGridIdsJson` looks like.
even if it does not load the full collection to get the ids (it uses `getAllIds`) it still loads 100k records in your case.

So I guess removing the `select all` buttons might make your grid load faster.

You can do that by implementing the method `_prepareMassaction` (most probably the method already exists) in your grid block and adding this line inside it:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);
```